# Replacing a cell value in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr

I am running a for loop within a funciton that loops over a group of variables, graps the coefficent associated with that variable from some dataframe. Then within my main dataframe I filter to find the right row and column based on an ID for the row and variable name for the column and add my coefficent to that cell's value.

```
for (k in 1:length(var.names)){
  var<-var.names[k] ## selects variable
  value.add<-coeff.proj.filter[coeff.proj.filter$Variable==var,2] # filter my 
                                                       # coefficent dataframe
  df2[df2$ID==id,var]<- # find the cell to replace
          df2[df2$ID==id,var]+value.add # take cell value
                                                            # and add value
)}
```

When I manually step through the function, everything works fine. I have done a whole bunch of manual checks. But I cannot not figure out where the issue is coming from.

The error I recieve when I run the funciotn is:

> Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero Called
>   from: `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, proj.data2$Player_ID == 
>       id, var, value = numeric(0))

This makes me think there is something wrong with the 'var' vector or an issue of how many times the for loop executes?

my function:

```
## Reproducable Code
## Variable<-c('var1','var2','var3')
## var.list<-Variable
## values<-c(10,20,30)
## coeff.proj<-data.frame(Variable,values)
## ID<-c('A','B','C','D')
## var1<-c(1,2,3,4)
## var2<-c(11,12,13,14)
## var3<-c(21,22,23,24)
## df<-data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3)
## id<-'A'
func1<- 
  function(df,var.list,id,coeff.proj){
  df2<-df

coeff.proj.filter<-coeff.proj[coeff.proj$Variable %in% var.list,]
var.names<-coeff.proj.filter$Variable
## let var.names<-c('var1','var2','var3') for dummy coding
## var.names is character vector of length 12
## For Loop copied from above
for (k in 1:length(var.names)){
  var<-var.names[k] ## selects variable
  value.add<-coeff.proj.filter[coeff.proj.filter$Variable==var,2] # filter my 
                                                       # coefficent dataframe
  df2[df2$ID==id,var]<- # find the cell to replace
          df2[df2$ID==id,var]+value.add # take cell value
                                                            # and add value
)}

## return(df2)
}
```

The only difference should be for `ID=='A'`, row 1 now shows 11,31, and 51. Even within this I cannot create a reprodcable example because my data is too big to show here. Primairly looking for tips on how the error could have occured or if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you determine which `id` values give the error and post an example that includes those rows?

Comment: It looks like there's an unnecessary ")" on line 28, it's ")}" and should be "}" only?